# How to create File directory like structure (shown in image) in jsp?(Please click the description below in order to open the image)

Tags: jsp

I want this type of structure to be created in JSP in which the user clicks on the arrow symbol and the child elements get expanded

[image: img]

Comment: question1: what are you trying to achieve? 
question2: you want to create a structure in a J2EE project having  `JSP` ?

Comment: Seems like you are looking for UI plugin for tree structure, perhaps you need to show us some relevant code as your initial efforts to achieve the same.

Comment: I want to show this type of structure as an output of jsp i.e. in html page.I am making a program to convert html to hypertree in jsp and to show it as hypertree i want to use this file structure in the output